# Linux - Control case fan speed based off of GPU temperature

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu, fan, temperature

I'm looking for a linux tool (I'm running Ubuntu), script, etc. that could control my case fan speeds based off of the GPU temperature.

I'm asking because I've recently built a new PC in the Node 202 case. The Node 202 has a little section for the graphics card and room for two fans below it. If I run my fans at full speed all the time the GPU temperature is fine, but if I run the fans based off of the system temperature the GPU gets pretty hot. I know that Speedfan for Windows can do this, and you could possibly run it with Wine, but I was wondering if there is a way (without installing new hardware) that I could do something similar as I would with Speedfan.

Another solution could just be too control fan speed based off of system temperature as it is now, but have it just run faster for the system temps that are listed lower. I'm not sure how to do that, though, and it might not really be effective.

Any help?

Edit:
Speedfan with Wine does *not* work.